# Using facade pattern with remoting?

Tags: design-patterns, remoting

I hear about using the facade design pattern with remoting but I can't see the relation between these 2 concepts or how facade would help in remoting scenarios.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facade contains code to implement the remoting, then forwards requests to whatever code handles your "business logic." This means that your business logic code is free of remoting stuff. This keeps it simpler and also lets you use the code in non-remote contexts, e.g. in unit tests or with a GUI front-end.

Comment: Is there an example of how the request would be forwarded to the business logic? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the Domain driven design sample....
http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/xref/overview-summary.html